# Initializing objects of my class with a string

Tags: c++, initialization, operator-overloading

I'm writing a polynomial class:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class polynomial
{
private:
    int coeff[300];
    int expo[300];
    int counter;
public:
    polynomial();
    polynomial(const polynomial&);
    polynomial operator-()const;
    polynomial& operator=(const polynomial);
    polynomial operator*(const polynomial)const;
    polynomial operator+(const polynomial)const;
    polynomial operator-(const polynomial)const;
    polynomial operator+(int)const;
    friend polynomial operator+(int,const polynomial);
    polynomial operator-(int)const;
    friend polynomial operator-(int,const polynomial);
    polynomial operator*(int)const;
    polynomial operator/(polynomial);
    friend polynomial operator*(int,const polynomial);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, polynomial&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, polynomial&);

};
```

I receive polynomial as a string like:
`+3x^2-10x+1` with `cin` object and then in `istream& operator>>(istream&, polynomial&)` I will extract it's coefficient and exponent.

Besides constructor and copy constructor and operators which I have overloaded, I should be able to initialize an object of class polynomial like:

`Polynomial p1 = "+5x^2-3";//(in main)`

I have tried overloading my copy assignment operator two time(besides which is already in code another one for a string)like:

`polynomial operator=(string)`

and I failed.

I really have no idea, how to initialize an object of class polynomial with a string. what are the ways for doing it?

Comment: I don't see a constructor that takes a string.  Second thing -- given the data members, there is no need for a user-defined copy constructor or assignment operator.  All you're doing by providing these functions is possibly introduce bugs.

Comment: Hi interesting, perhaps add a constructor `polynomial(const string &s)`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right, but I had to add them  in my code and in constructor I had to only set coefficients to zero and take string with `cin`.

Comment: If you're talking about the copy-assignment functions, then no, you didn't have to add them at all in your code.  The copy-assignment functions are there to make copies, and the compiler would have done so automatically and without error.  If your member variables were pointers or held resources, then a user-defined copy-assignment functions would be created.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah you are completely right, by I had to I meant my instructor told me to so, not that they are really needed.

Comment: The teacher really shouldn't have you write things that are not needed.  Providing your own copy constructor and assignment op when not needed opens you up for bugs, and if not bugs, stops the compiler from producing efficient code, since the compiler knows how to make shallow copies optimally.  It can also potentially change the traits for your class type when you provide these functions (that goes for the empty destructor also).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) that takes a single argument of a `std::string` type.

The constructor definition would look something like:

```
polynomial(std::string const &s) {
  // use s to construct
}
```

However, you still can't construct a `polynomial` object the way you want:

```
polynomial p1 = "+5x^2-3";
```

because the compiler would need to make 2 implicit conversions to call the appropriate constructor. Note that you can still do:

```
polynomial p1 {"+5x^2-3"}; 
// or
polynomial p1 = std::string{"+5x^2-3"};
```

To solve this, you can add a constructor that takes a `char const *`, and delegates to the `std::string` constructor:

```
polynomial(char const * c) : polynomial(std::string{c}) {}
```

and now your code snippet should work.

Comment: `polynomial(std::string const &s) {...}` ... `polynomial p1 = "+5x^2-3";` [doesn't work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RGlEitlccqqZsFHK) because you are asking the compiler to make two implicit conversions.  Instead you can do `polynomial p1 ("+5x^2-3");` or define a constructor with signature `polynomial(const char *)`

Comment: @PaulSanders true, fixed the answer.

Comment: @cigien what are the two implicit conversions that compiler have to make?

Comment: @PaulSanders sorry what are the two implicit conversions that compiler have to make?

Comment: @hanie From `const char *` to `const std::string &`, and then from `const std::string &` to `polynomial`.